# Different counters in one pass of list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

I have a list of dictionaries in Python. Every element of the list corresponds to one day, and every element of the dictionary has information on a user's minute-by-minute activity.

Example:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {u'activity': 
        {u'values': [
            [1407729600, 3.0],
            [1407729660, 2.0],
            [1407729720, 2.0],
            [1407729780, 3.0],
            [1407729840, 1.0],
            [1407729900, 4.0],
            [1407729960, 2.0],
            [1407730020, 5.0],
            [1407730080, 6.0],
            [1407730140, 2.0],
            [1407730200, 1.0],
            [1407730260, 2.0],
            [1407730320, 1.0],
            [1407730380, 2.0],
            [1407730440, 1.0]]}},
    {u'activity': 
        {u'values': [
            [1407788340, 2.0],
            [1407788400, 2.0],
            [1407788460, 3.0],
            [1407788520, 2.0],
            [1407788580, 2.0],
            [1407788640, 2.0],
            [1407788700, 2.0],
            [1407788760, 2.0],
            [1407788820, 2.0],
            [1407788880, 3.0],
            [1407788940, 2.0],
            [1407789000, 3.0],
            [1407789060, 2.0],
            [1407789120, 3.0],
            [1407789180, 3.0],
            [1407789240, 2.0],
            [1407789300, 3.0],
            [1407789360, 3.0],
            [1407789420, 2.0],
            [1407789480, 3.0],
            [1407789540, 2.0]]}}]
```

Now, I want to have different aggregations of the data. For example, I would like to have the count of activity per hour per day of the week. This I can do with the following piece of code:

```
c = Counter()

step_values_unlist = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                          [d['activity']['values'] 
                           for d in list_of_dicts]))

week_hour_dict = [{(time.gmtime(x[0])[3], time.gmtime(x[0])[6]):x[1]} 
                  for x in step_values_unlist]

for d in week_hour_dict:
    c.update(d)
```

Whilst this is OK, I will need to do other aggregations also, since this is part of a feature vector generation for the subsequent ML step. As an example, I would like to have counts of weeks with activity on all seven days etc. These can also be done individually via various counters by reading the list of dictionaries again for a new counter. However, this will be time-consuming since the list of dictionaries is large and this is running (via PySpark) for 1M+ users. It is preferable that we not read through this large list of dicts multiple times. Is there a way to compute these measures in one single pass of the list of dicts ?

Comment: Can you write a function that accepts a dictionary, operates on the values, and returns a tuple or a namedtuple with the aggregations you want?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would summarize your question as follows:

> Is there a way to compute multiple operations in one single pass of a list of dicts?

In the general case this shouldn't really matter. If you're computing 15 operations, you're going to have to do a computation with each element 15 different times.

In the case when you have a detailed idea of the operations of each of your metrics, you may be able to factor out some of the operations to eliminate redundant work. For example you may need to take into account the average per minute in multiple metrics for normalization purposes. It's up to you to write your functions so they can share this average value: compute it first and then pass it to each one.